# How can I tell autoconf to create a Windows DLL?

Tags: autoconf

I have a C library that has been working both in Unix (compiled into a `.so` file using `autoconf`) and in Windows (compiled into a `.dll` file) with MS Visual C++ Express. I now want to change it so that instead of MS Visual C++ Express it uses `autoconf` on Windows as well, with MinGW/MSYS.

I added this to `configure.ac`:

```
LT_INIT([win32-dll])
```

and this to `Makefile.am`:

```
libdickinson_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined
```

and re-run `aclocal`, `automake`, and `autoconf`; but when, in Windows, I try `/.configure` and `make`, I don't get a DLL anywhere.

What else do I have to do to get the DLL?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had this statement:

```
libdickinson_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined
```

in the wrong `Makefile.am`; it was in the `Makefile.am` of the `src` subdirectory; I also added it to the top-level `Makefile.am`. I'm not certain it was this that did the trick, but it now works.